# timer control to refresh grid

Tags: c#, .net, timer, grid

I have a grid to which I bound data in Page_Load in this way:

```
List<ProductEventCheck> ruleset = (from s in (this.Page as BasePage).DbContext.ProductEventChecks
                                  where s.Sequence != 0
                                  orderby s.Sequence
                                  select s).ToList<ProductEventCheck>();
rulesGrid.DataSource = ruleset;
rulesGrid.DataBind();
```

So, I have 3 columns Name, Descriptoin and status where name and description are from Database while status depends on storedprocedures run. Basically the Name field is a procedure name. So, i have 21 stored procedures which run. So, i wanted to run a timer so that i can show the status field processing every 3 sec but the code i wrote is refreshing only after all the procedures are run. Can you please help me in knowing the problem or mistake i have been doing?

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string proc = "";
    int result = 0;
    GridItemCollection gridRows = rulesGrid.Items;
    foreach (GridDataItem data in gridRows)
    {
        proc = Convert.ToString(data["Name"].Text);

        RunProcedure(proc, out result);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(result) == 0)
        {
            data["statusResult"].Text = "Failure";
            RadButtonContinue.Enabled = false;

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            data["statusResult"].Text = "Completed";
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: It seems like the actual running of the procedures should be somewhere other than the timer tick handler (and the timer tick handler would just update the status on the grid)?